# Add comment field to custom drupal 7 module

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm developing a custom drupal module which generates pages dynamically. You can compare this with a calendar. However I spend much time to search for a solution for allowing to add comments to that content.

I think that the design of the comments module could be a problem because it seems to depend on a node id. Is it possible to add a simple prefix to avoid collisions with nodes?

I found the comments hook but no way to add the comment form. Could you point me a solution?

Comment: Just wondering - have you found a solution to this problem yet?

Comment: Well yes, but it is very tricky. Basically I called a function that is called when a new type is generated which generates some metadata for the comment module. Then it is not so hard. See also this [dublicate](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35953/add-comments-to-custom-node) which helped me. Maybe If I have some more time I'll add here a full explanation.

Comment: Thanks - will have a look at that link! :)